# How to load a widget in Wordpress theme installation?

Tags: wordpress, widget, installation, themes

I have recorded some sidebars on my Wordpress theme, but I want to load some widgets upon the theme installation, is helping me?

Below the code of sidebar:

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Widgets',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="row widget %2$s"><div class="widget-section">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing id in that code. It should be

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Widgets',
        'id' => 'footer-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="row widget %2$s"><div class="widget-section">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
```

And you can call it on your theme like

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-widget' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already have a dynamic sidebar area created, I want now is populate with her dynamically widgets in my theme installation.